# EntityManager properties get lost after transaction finishes?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, jta

I have some code running on Glassfish 4 that sets properties on the EntityManager(javax.persistence.EntityManager), this happens during a transaction.

On another transaction I want to read the properties and I see they are gone.

I see that in both cases it is the same EntityManager object(actually it is an EntityManagerWrapper):

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper@5a346e8f

Are properties only valid for the lifetime of the transaction?

I get the EntityManager through injection(the object that is injected de facto is the wrapper mentioned above):

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = IEntityManagerService.DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    protected void setManager(final EntityManager manager) {
        assert manager != null;
        this.manager = manager;
    }
```

Comment: You mean em.setProperty ? They should be held for the lifetime of the EntityManager; there is nothing in the javadocs/spec to say that an implementation can throw them away after commit of any txn. Perhaps this "wrapper" is the culprit, and the real EntityManager has them - so why not try to get a handle on the real EM?

Comment: @NeilStockton yes, em.setProperty. The EM Wrapper is injected(see edit to OP), so Im not sure if I would be violating Container rules by just getting the underlying EM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a default behavior of container-managed `EntityManager`.

Actual instances of `EntityManager` are created and destroyed per transaction, and `EntityManagerWrapper` is just a proxy that delegates calls to `EntityManager` associated with the current transaction.

If your `EntityManager` is injected into stateful object, you can configure it to span multiple transactions [using `type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html#type()), but I don't think that it's what you need in your case.

Also, it's not quite clear why do you want to keep `EntityManager` properties between transactions. `EntityManager.setProperty()` is usually used to configure vendor-specific options of the underlying JPA implementation, not as a way to communicate between transactions.

Comment: Is there any official doc that explains this? It is not mentioned in the EntityManager docs. I want to keep properties because some of them are stuff like security roles of the currently logged in user. I don't want to reset them in every transaction.

Comment: Behavior of container-managed `EntityManager` is described in the JPA specification. `EntityManager` is not a right place to keep security roles. I think Glassfish should have some special infrastructure for security.